# Scraping with selenium, can not get a button to click and load a hidden table with the data i want

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a form that has nav tabs that display 4 different ways to search through the requested information. The URL loads into the tab that I want to search from and with the date fields automatically filled in. When a human user wants to look through the info they only have to click the search button that is in the selected tab, which enabled a loading screen and fills and enables a table below with the data I want to scrape. I am using python 3 and selenium currently.

Button code :

```
<button type="submit" id="community-search" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: submitSearch, enable: searchEnabled">Search</button>
```

This is my code right now:

```
#start of code after imports
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
chromedriver = dir_path + "/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options, executable_path = chromedriver)

# LOGS INTO THE SITE 
browser.get('https://***.com/')
username = browser.find_element_by_name('UserName')
username.send_keys('***') 
password = browser.find_element_by_name('Password')
password.send_keys('***')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#sign-in').click()
# LOGIN WORKS

#GOES TO THE SCHEDUALS PAGE 
browser.get('https://***.com/Schedules')
#I KNOW IT IS NAVIGATING TO THIS PAGE

# I HAVE TRIED WAITING AND FOUND NO LUCK, TRYING TO CLICK THE BUTTON LEADS TO A HUGE LIST OF TRACEBACKS
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('community-search').click()
#WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'community-search'))).click

#end of code
```

Errors-

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Project.py", line 29, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('community-search').click()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 589, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"community-search"}
```

I am fairly new to python and web scraping, this is my first post so I hope this was enough info. Any help would be very much appreciated

[ImageOfSiteBeforeBtnPress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txx2C.png)
[ImageOfSiteAfterBtnPress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMiO5.png)

Comment: Have you tried `browser.find_element_by_id('community-search')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"community-search"}
```

The error clearly says **NoSuchElementException**, as the *css-selector* which you have used as follows doesn't identifies a unique element :

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('community-search').click()
```

Incase **community-search** is the value of the `id`, a proper `css_selector` would be (adding a `#` before the value) as follows :

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#community-search").click()
```

But as you are trying to search the *WebElement* soon after invoking `browser.get()` you may need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in-conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause as [element_to_be_clickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#community-search"))).click()
```

Incase you want to use the `id` attribute you can use the following line of code as follows :

```
browser.find_element_by_id("community-search").click()
```

To click on the *WebElement* using the `id` attribute along with *WebDriverWait* :

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "community-search"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, using the id worked in finding it and I know what I am looking up now to find more help. But now that selenium is recognizing the button even after waiting it is saying that the element is not visible.

Comment: I ended up creating an element from the closest visible object and then tabbing over and pressing enter on the button.  elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="task-status"]')
elem.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 2, Keys.ENTER)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector is missing `#`since `community-search` is an id.

So instead of:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('community-search').click()
```

It should be:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#community-search').click()
```

Another way to do it is:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('community-search').click()
```